Can vibronic coupling make laporte forbidden transitions more allowed?
I am currently investigating absorption spectra and I came across a possibly forbidden 1Ag -> 1Ag electronic transition of an organic molecule. Now I was wondering, is it possible for a Laporte forbidden transition to become more allowed or more visible if certain vibronic coupling occurs?

In general, yes, but it will depend on the particular point group having a vibration that changes the symmetry of that transition so the integral changes from $\int \psi_i\mu\psi_fd\tau=0$ to $\int \psi_i\varphi_{vib}\mu\psi_fd\tau\ne 0$.  This happens in benzene which has a forbidden $S_0\to S_1$ transition but becomes allowed with an $e_{2g}$ vibration.
